# How to import jdk 9 maven spring boot 2 projects into eclipse ee oxygen without Dynamic Web Module 3.0 facet hacks?

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I would like to import existing jdk9(or 10) maven projects into eclipse ee Oxygen.

Even when specifyig 1.9 in the pom in various ways, there are eclipse problem markers displayed about:

- Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
- **Dynamic Web Module 3.1 requires Java 1.7 or newer.**

I've tried making my pom build plugins include:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.9</source>
        <target>1.9</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or these properties at the top:

```
<maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
```

I can get rid of the "There are no JREs..." eclipse problem marker by ensuring settings like:

- Windows - Preferences - Java - jdk 1.9
- Project - Properties - Build Path - jdk 1.9
- Project - Properties - Java Compiler - 1.9 compliance

Shouldn't these Project settings not be needed though since my pom specifies 1.9?  - Isn't m2 eclipse supposed to import settings as 1.9?

I'm unable to get this problem marker removed:  "Dynamic Web Module 3.1 requires Java 1.7 or newer."

Things I have tried are:

- Setting different combinations of: the project facets "Dynamic Web Module" to 3.1 or 3.0 - along with setting the Java facet to 9.
- Setting both of those facets to unchecked
- Editing the eclipse-generated .settings ~facets.xml file to set the "Dynamic Web Module" to 3.0/3.1/ or removing the line from the file
- Specifying an older javax.servlet-api dependency

  javax.servlet
    javax.servlet-api
    3.1.0
    provided

I'm configuring Spring with annotations - I do not have a Web.xml.  My pom packaging is WAR.

My JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to jdk 9 - on Windows 7.  I have %JAVA_HOME%\bin in the PATH variable.

I don't have older jdk's installed anywhere.  I have a jdk10 installed, but these errors still happen when only having one jdk installed.

I used to be able to import maven projects into eclipse with no issues when I was using Eclipse Neon with jdk 8.

I updated my poms to jdk 9 so I could move to Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE

In between test runs of the new versions of everything - I do these cache cleanup attempts:

- Delete eclipse extracted zip
- Delete [userhome]/.eclipse
- Delete [source-project]/.settings
- Delete project from ide
- Re-Extract Eclipse, Set Windows Preferences jdk9(if not already) reimport pom

I tried using the Spring Tool Suite variant - but experienced the same "Dynamic Web Module 3.1 requires Java 1.7 or newer." error

I've looked at other's posts - that are usually 1 year older than now.  They usually metnion all the things I've tried above - 
but my "Dynamic Web Module 3.1 requires Java 1.7 or newer." error has not gone away as it has for others.

Is this a known issue that doesn't work for anyone on the latest versions - or is it assumed to work?

I've noticed and seen others comment that running maven builds through eclipse causes those previous "eclipse jdk version settings" to go away,
like it tries to reimport the settings from the pom again with m2eclipse - but gives the undesired effect of not importing the 1.9 setting from the 
pom - so I have to set it again in Eclipse settings.  This wasn't happenging with Eclipse Neon and jdk8

Here are some links of things I tried above:

[Changing Dynamic Web Module version in Eclipse Maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405212/changing-dynamic-web-module-version-in-eclipse-maven-project)

https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0-error-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use "9" for the java version instead of "1.9", so the section in the pom appears as:

```
<maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
```

That allows the m2 eclipse plugin to import the projects using its expected representation of the java version number.