# Spring MVC passes null value on next page

Tags: java, spring, request-mapping

I am a beginner in SpringMVC JSP and I am creating a simple project that passes values using POST Method.

1st page: hello.jsp

```
<body>
<h1>Record Form</h1>
    <form name="test" id="test" action="test.jsp" method="post">
        <p>Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" /></p>
        <p>Address: <input type = "text" name = "address" /></p>
        <p>Remarks: <input type = "text" name = "remarks" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
```

2nd page: test.jsp

```
<body>
<h1>Result</h1>
    <p>name: ${record.name}</p>
    <p>address: ${record.address}</p>
    <p>remarks: ${record.remarks}</p>
    <a href="hello.jsp">Submit another message</a>
</body>
```

Record.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Record {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String remarks;
 //setters getters..
```

HelloController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired


    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String hello(Record record) {
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = POST)
    public String test(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("address") String address, @RequestParam("remarks") String remarks, Model model) {
        Record record = new Record();
        record.setName(name);
        record.setAddress(address);
        record.setRemarks(remarks);
        model.addAttribute("record", record);
        return "/test";
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I click submit, no value was passed. I have been checking my code and I couldn't see what's wrong. Can anyone help me out please?

[image]

When changing codes to `<form action="test">` only, this error occurs. Also if I changed to this `<form action="/test">` based on what I have searched. Nothing works. See image below.
[image]

and I already have this in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

for my pom.xml, i already added this

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you try this `<a href="/reservation/bookingForm">Click here for reservation.</a>`

Comment: @Mohale still not working

Comment: Do you have a `reservation-page.jsp` in your `/WEB-INF/jsp/` directory?

Comment: @MAC please refer, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22405212/8700934

Comment: @M.Deinum yes I have.

Comment: @Lakshan Still did not help. Is it possible that the cause is because I am missing Java Path Entry?

Comment: @MAC, do I understand it correctly that the part of your question about the redirect is irrelevant? I. e. you just need to solve the problem of getting error 404 when going to `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTextField/reservation/bookingForm`, right?

Comment: I change my question to a simpler one. I tried to make it from start so I can see what went wrong when passing that values.

Comment: Oh, so you've changed it completely... :) Your original question linked to [a tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-form-text-field) - I would recommend you *not* to use it at the 1st place. It is full of mistakes right from the start, invalid dependencies in pom.xml, missing Java version 1.7+ requirement, etc.

Comment: @PetrBodnár Thank you so much for telling me that. I was really confused what went wrong with my first one. Now I will proceed with my new issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these things MAC

Change your web.xml like this:

```
<welcome-file-list> 
 <welcome-file>hello.jsp</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list> 
<servlet> 
<servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name> 
 <servlet-class> 
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 
 </servlet-class> 
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
 <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name> 
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> 
<context-param> 
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
 <param-value> 
  /WEB-INF/mvc-servlet.xml 
 </param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Make sure you have  `mvc-servlet.xml` under `/WEB-INF/` location

Also, specify the location of jsp file in `mvc-servlet.xml` like

```
<bean 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
<property name="prefix" value="/" /> 
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
</bean>
```

(@MAC - in your case all your jsp file are at root level.)

This might help you to solve the issue.

Comment: if i add those codes to web.xml and spring-servlet.xml, the index.jsp will now return error 404 as well @Atul

Comment: I am assuming you have mentioned the index.jsp in welcome file list in web.xml file. If not then add it  **<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>**

Comment: This will only load the same configuration twice and will not solve the issue.

Comment: The error message shows that, you have to use at lease Java 1.7 or more. Configure required version of Java and run the application again.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, add index.jsp file as a welcome file. In index.jsp you have to redirect it to the location you want like, **<body>
 <%response.sendRedirect("reservation/bookingForm"); %>
</body>** . One question, if you are accessing full path, is it working?

Comment: One more question, where is your index.jsp file, is it in /WEB-INF/jsp folder? If it is there then you have to move the file to the level where WEB-INF folder is and then try.

Comment: @Atul I think my Controller is not called from View

Comment: If I use `action="test.jsp"` it will display next page but no values. if i change to `action="test"`, error 404 appears. can you tell me what was wrong?  i am already using `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` in web.xml

Comment: @MAC, please try "/test" instead of "test" only.

Comment: @Atul I did, still no

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204022/discussion-between-atul-and-mac).

Comment: Good that you resolved it in the end. A near-pro tip: Don't forget to specify in the answer what was actually wrong - I suppose it was a misconfigured Spring in this case? @MAC, also it will help you a lot if you add logging (like slf4j / log4j) to your app next time, so you can see what's going on (wrong) in your app...

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to change this:

```
<form name="test" id="test" action="test.jsp" method="post">
```

To this:

```
<form name="test" id="test" action="test" method="post">
```

Otherwise your controller method mapped at `/test` will not be called and `test.jsp` is rendered directly, with the `record` model variable being empty.

Comment: An error 404 occurs when I don't add `.jsp` on `action` part

Comment: i updated my question, adding the results when i change code to `action="test"` and i also added my web.xml and pom.xml, can you please check and see if you can tell me what went wrong?